# Java SimpleJdbcCall: stored procedure results are not mapped

Tags: java, database, spring-boot

I have following spring boot code that calls stored procedure.

```
     SimpleJdbcCall dbCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withSchemaName("MySchema")
            .withProcedureName("spName")
            .declareParameters(
                    new SqlParameter("param1", Types.INTEGER),
                    new SqlParameter("param2", Types.TINYINT),
                    new SqlParameter("param3", Types.INTEGER))
            .returningResultSet("some_return_value", (RowMapper<Integer>) (rs, rowNum) -> {
                int id = rs.getInt("columnName");
                System.out.println(id);
                return id;
            });


    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    params.addValue("param1", 12345);
    params.addValue("param2", 2);
    params.addValue("param3", 12345);

    List res = dbCall.executeFunction(List.class, params);
```

For test purposes I try to get a list of ids. Other parameters I'll add later. In result, `res` variable is always `null`. 
`System.out.println(id);` in `RowMapper` shows me correct ids in console window.

Could someone explain me what's wrong in my code?

**Update 15/11/2017**
I found that if I change `List res = dbCall.executeFunction(List.class, params);` to `Map<String,Object> response = getQACall.execute(params);` it works. Any ideas why it does not work with `executeFunction`?

Comment: Did you try printing the values?

Comment: yes, in console values are correct. I updated the question

Comment: I'd suggest trying to run spring boot in debug mode. Probably for some reason it can't cast/map result set to List class.